# Java profiling within eclipse - call stack

Tags: java, eclipse, threadpool

Does anywone know a good profiler for call stack and thread in the same time.
maybe something that can be slowed down to really see whats happening on those threads, waits on objects, synchronized metods and so on..

Comment: By default, in eclipse profiler available..Or you can use eclipse memory anlyzer(MAT) plugin..

Answer (score 1):

Try [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/download.html) - it is free and rich-featured. But not as much as [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) - greates Java profiler tool! It can do everything you can imagine with your code and VM (and things you cannot imagine too). But it costs 499$.

Answer (score 1):

please try this

following is the instructions to switch built in profiling database with newer version

1. close your eclipse ide
2. browse to your-workspace-folder/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.dltk.core.index.sql.h2
3. copy all files under this folder to another location as a backup
4. and delete all files with .db extension
5. download latest version of H2 database for All Platforms zip from this [link](http://h2database.com/html/main.html)
6. goto your-eclipse-folder\plugins\ and find the file something like org.h2_1.1.117.v201105142352.jar and copy it to some place as a backup
7. extract the zip file downloaded on step 5
8. you will find the file h2-1.3.170.jar under h2\bin\ folder
9. rename h2-1.3.170.jar to the file name from the step 6 which is org.h2_1.1.117.v201105142352.jar
10. after this you can put the file renamed in step 9 into the folder your-eclipse-folder\plugins\
11. you can try to start your eclipse

please let me know if this makes your eclipse run faster